# Operations with function handle in matlab

Tags: matlab, equation-solving, function-handle

Could you please help me with the following issue: I have the following function handle:

```
r1 = @(lambda) b + lambda*(r - b); % r and b are vectors of return data
```

I want to find the optimal lambdas that set me a mean function to zero, for a given set of powers within that function. What I tried to do and didn't work, as it returns me an error for undefined operators for input arguments of type 'function_handle' is:

```
lambda0 = 0.3;
for a = 2:10    %power coefficient
S1(a) = fzero(mean((r - b)*r1.^(1/(a - 1))),lambda0);
end
```

Any suggestion as to how to go about this problem is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) accepts a function handle as the first input. As you currently have it, you're trying to pass a statement as the first input. This statement can't even be properly evaluated because you are trying to perform numerical operations on a function handle (more on this in a bit).

You need to instead do something like this where we create a *new* function handle that evaluates the *original* function handle and performs the other operations you need.

```
S1(a) = fzero(@(lambda)mean((r - b)*r1(lambda).^(1/(a - 1))),lambda0);
```

## Further Explanation

Performing operations on a function handle is *not* the same as performing them on the result.

So for example, if we had a function handle:

```
func = @(x)2*x;
```

If we evaluation this, by calling it with an input value for `x`

```
func(2)

    4
```

This works as we would expect. If now we really want the value `(2*x)^2`, we could try to write it the way that you wrote your statement in your question

```
func2 = func^2;
```

We will get an error!

> Undefined operator '^' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

This does not work because MATLAB attempts to apply the `^` operation to the *function handle* itself and not the *value of the evaluated function handle*.

Instead, we would need to create a *new* function handle that essentially wraps the other one and performs any additional options:

```
func2 = @(x)func(x)^2;
func2(2)

    16
```

## Bringing it Full-Circle

So if we go back to your question, you defined your anonymous function `r1` like this.

```
r1 = @(lambda) b + lambda*(r - b); % r and b are vectors of return data
```

This all looks great. You have one input argument and you reference `r` and `b` from the parent workspace.

Now when you call `fzero` you try to perform operations on this function handle in hopes of creating a new function handle.

```
mean((r - b)*r1.^(1/(a - 1)))
```

Like we just showed this will result in a very similar error

> Undefined operator .^ for input arguments of type 'function_handle'

So we need to wrap this into a new function.

```
newfunc = @(lambda)mean((r - b)*r1(lambda).^(1 / (a - 1)));
```

Now we can safely pass this to `fzero`.

```
result = fzero(newfunc, lambda0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation, it really helped me to understand the mechanism behind the problem at hand.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: would it be possible to constrain the values of lambdas in [0,1] using fzero?

Comment: @Astrid You would pass the `[lower, upper]` bounds for lambda as the second input rather than specifying `lambda0`. [The Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html#inputarg_x0)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I replace lambda0 with [0,1] I get the following error: Error using fzero (line 273)
The function values at the interval endpoints must differ in sign.

Comment: @Astrid Yup. Check the documentation link above and it explains why that is.

Comment: I also tried with [-0.00001, 1], but it returns me the same result as when I put lambda0, so it doesn't really constrain lambda to be in [0,1].

Comment: @Astrid maybe open a new question so others can help you more

Comment: Thanks again for your help!